# Angular 2 router doesn't resolve child auxiliary route

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, router

I'm trying to use an auxiliary route for a modal window. Regardless of what I try I can't get it to resolve. I just get routing errors. Here's my approach...

*app.component.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
```

*admin-routing.module.ts*

```
...
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'accounts',
        loadChildren: './accounts/accounts.module#AccountsModule'
      },{...}
    ]
  }
];
...
```

*accounts-routing.module.ts*

```
...
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AccountsIndexComponent
      },{
        path: 'new',
        component: AccountsNewComponent
      },{
        path: ':id',
        component: AccountsShowComponent
      },{
        path: ':id/edit',
        component: AccountsEditComponent,
        outlet: 'modal'
      }
    ]
  }
];
...
```

*modal.service.ts*

```
  ...
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  open(route:Array<any>) {
    this.router.navigate(
      [{outlets: {drawer: route}}], {relativeTo: this.route}
    )
  }
  ...
```

When I call the `ModalService.open([account.id, 'edit'])` it tries to navigate to `/admin/accounts(modal:1/edit)` which is what I *think* it's supposed to do. But I just get an error that it can't match the `1/edit` url segment.

```
NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/admin/accounts(modal:1/edit)', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1/edit')
```

I've tried the following and they didn't work either...

```
ModalService.open(['accounts', account.id, 'edit'])
ModalService.open(['admin','accounts', account.id, 'edit'])
```

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Never did. We gave up and decided to display modals using the ng-bootstrap library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726) in the router that prevents child auxiliary routes from being loaded when the parent path is empty, which is what you are doing in `accounts-routing.module.ts`:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',                 // <--- cannot have an empty parent path...
    children: [
      {
         path: ':id/edit',
         component: AccountsEditComponent,
         outlet: 'modal'      // <--- ...with child aux outlet
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To work around the issue, we must supply something for the path. For instance, if you name your path `'accounts'`:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'accounts', 
    ...
```

then you can navigate to your aux route either from a routerLink:

```
<a [routerLink]="['accounts', {outlets: {'modal': ['1/edit']}}]">
```

or programatically:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('accounts/(modal:1/edit)')
```

Here is a [working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1BxbCn3ZR8yd0lnHZBU?p=preview) I made to figure this out and demonstrate successfully loading a child auxiliary route.

Comment: Ugh. This issue kicked my butt for a day or two before I gave up. Looks like i'm stuck with a different approach until this is fixed. Our app is way too big to drop lazy loading for one feature. Thanks for the reply @Mike Chamberlain!

Comment: Would you really have to drop lazy loading? Would it not be enough to include an extra (meaningless) URL segment in your lazy loaded module, so eg. your new account route would be something like `/admin/accounts/dummy/new`? Ugly, but might work?

Comment: yeah, that would work, but I think it might be a little ugly for me :) I think at this point we'll stick with bootstrap modals and maybe refactor once the router is fixed

Comment: First answer to this question that actually gets to the bottom of it. Been looking for several hours. Yes, there's a bug, and it's kind of a tough call whether to work around it or live without the named outlet functionality.